# Why did they start Wendelstein 7-X With Helium?

Tags: plasma-physics, fusion

Just saw the first Hydrogen plasma at the Wendelstein reactor. I haven't found anywhere that gives a good explanation as to why they first used a Helium plasma - can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Well, I'd start up a new plasma system using an inert gas - I'd rather find out any problems with a non-explosive gas mixture. Once I know that everything works (vacuum, valves, no leaks, plasma actually ignites, ...) I would move on to the more exciting mixtures.

Comment: @JonCuster: Where is your sense of adventure? Does it not interest you to test out the capabilities of the local fire fighting department during your first run? ;-)

Comment: Fine - start it up with disilane then - at least one can easily see the excitement!

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks Jon, kind of obvious really! Could you post it as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer:

Well, I'd start up a new plasma system using an inert gas - I'd rather find out any problems with a non-explosive gas mixture. Once I know that everything works (vacuum, valves, no leaks, plasma actually ignites, ...) I would move on to the more exciting mixtures.

Remember - for any non-trivial system (and even many trivial ones!), the chance that it will all work perfectly the first time is very slim. It is always a good idea to test with as low a hazard level as possible, and design your system to be 'rescue-able' if something goes wrong (e.g. main vacuum pumps will always fail when the chamber is full of a pyrophoric gas - what are you going to do now?).

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding the reason for using helium first is slightly different: It is correct that helium provides a *safe* way to start an experiment but *safe* in that sense that when you use hydrogen you usually have a problem with recycling and refuelling from the wall (hydrogen being bounded to some wall materials, leaves the wall-material, called *desorption*). This leads to an increase in the overall density which leads to a decrease of the temperature and you want to have high temperature.

In addition, the walls will be *dirty* for the initial experiments and bombardment with helium helps to clean them (hydrogen instead would tend to stick to the wall material, being *adsorbed* there).

**update**: As asked by @Emilio Pisanty, I found a reference in which it is stated:

> It is known from previous fusion experiments that the walls can absorb and subsequently release significant amounts of hydrogen when hydrogen plasmas are used. Without a divertor, there is a risk that the shot-to-shot reproducibility of the plasma density evolution will be poor in this early campaign. Helium, being a noble gas, is much less likely to be loaded to the walls than hydrogen, and the shot-to-shot reproducibility of helium plasma density evolution is expected to be better.

Source: [doi:10.1088/0029-5515/55/12/126001](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0029-5515/55/12/126001)

Comment: That's an interesting take. Have you got any good materials for further reading?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I updated the answer to include a reference